# android-support-v7-appcompat error on eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-appcompat

I added the android-support-v7-appcompat libraries with resources in my eclipse, however it has an error found in the folder res/values-23

```
error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
```

I have read that the solution is just to change the target to android-21 in the project properties. I have done this and even clean my project countless of times. I also have installed the sdk platforms for android version 21. But none of the said solution worked for me. please help.. thank you..

Comment: The thing is, Eclipse is being left behind and they suggest everyone to use Android Studio http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Comment: Support revision 23 request compiling against API 23.